# POSIX (~*) search with Postgre. Results order

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, sql-order-by, posix

I have a query that gives me a result based in a search term.

I'm using POSIX search from postgre (~*): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

So for example, if I search "**ed**"

The result will be something like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Victoria",
            "last_name": "Ojeda Acu–a",
        },
        {
            "name": "Eduardo Daniel",
            "last_name": "Ordo–ez",
        },
        {
            "name": "Ludmila Daiana",
            "last_name": "Paredes Sosa",
        }
      ]
}
```

- So, the first result has ed present in last_name: oj**ed**a
- the second result has ed present in in name: **Ed**uardo
- the third result has ed present in in last_name: Pa**ed**es

This is my (simplified) query:

```
SELECT u.name, u.last_name FROM user u WHERE u.name ~* :searchTerm OR u.last_name ~* :searchTerm
```

I consider that **Ed**uardo is the most accurate result for my search because I searched in that order **"ED"** (it could be some last_name with ED at the begin too), so I would like to get Eduardo as my first result is there any way to achieve this?

I know that I can use LIKE %:searchTerm but I want to search in the entire string, but get the results in some predefined order.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY starts_with(u.name, :searchTerm) DESC
```

This relies on `FALSE < TRUE`.

Comment: I tried, but I get this:

{
"SELECT u.name FROM user_sys u WHERE u.name ~* 'ed' ORDER BY NOT (u.name ~* 'ed')": [
 {
  "name" : "Eduardo Andre"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Gabriela Edith"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Educación Física"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Andrea Soledad"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Soledad"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Federico"
 },
 {
  "name" : "David Edgardo"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Alfredo"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Anahi Soledad"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Edward"
 },
 {
  "name" : "Pamela Mercedes"
 }
]}

Comment: Is not ordered by Ed names first

Comment: First, you changed the `WHERE` condition. Second, please describe the desired order accurately.

Comment: I just simplified the WHERE, instead name and lastname just name.
I want all name starting with Ed  (my search term) first, then the others. So I will get a more accurate order for my search

Comment: I see. I have adapted the answer.